# How to pass a string from back end (java) to the front end(typescript) and have it appear on UI?

Tags: javascript, java, string, frontend, backend

Simply put, I'm trying to pass a string from my java back end to my typescript front end so that this same string will display in the UI. Neatly below the purple bar like so:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUBJZ.png)

I think in the back end I have to return a string, send it through a controller, and have the front end receive the string from there but I've had limited success doing that so far.

Rather than debug my code, I was wondering if anyone here could point me to a simple tutorial or project that does exactly what I'm trying to do: Take a string from the back end, return it, have it received by the front end, then have that same string displayed on the UI. That way I can just mirror the implementation. I've tried googling for simple examples like that but I've come up empty so far.

Comment: You mean you want to load a string from the backend at some point after the page has loaded? That is done using fetch(). If however you want this to happen when some event happens on the *backend*, you need socket.io or a similar solution that allows messages to be sent from the backend (because the backend is usually passive only, waiting for requests from the frontend)

Comment: "If however you want this to happen when some event happens on the backend"..... This is the train of thought Im on. I input some text in a textbox. The front end (typescript) sends it to the backend via the controller in the backend. The backend (java) receives the data and completes a segment of code and outputs a string. And now I want to take that string in the back end and return it back to the front end to be displayed on the front page. Know any projects on github or general tutorials that walk me through how to do that last sentence specifically?

Comment: What you describe is a frontend event (submitting a form). Which means you use fetch(). For simple text you can use a GET param. Basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/L81to3ag/

Answer (score 0):

As you just want to understand the direction/Suggestion on How to achieve the requirement. Few things you need to consider **:**

- You have to make a decision that you require to use any frontend related frameworks/libraries or you want to do that in pure JavaScript ?
- To get the data from Java backend you have to make an AJAX call from the page and simply bind that in UI DOM.

In pure JS, You can bind the string with the help of element ID.

```js
const str = 'This string is coming from API';

document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```

If you are going to use any `library/framework` then there is a way `one-way`/`two-way` data binding. I am just showing an example based on `Vue.js` for the demo purpose.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: null
  },
  mounted() {
    const str = 'This string is coming from API';
    this.message = str;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```